# Why is a property clearly pointing to a function when logged but returning undefined when referenced in the same line of code?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using the Node.js `cluster` module for multi-threading and devised a simple messaging system to feel similar to the socket.io messaging I'm used to. The (thread version of the) class looks like this:

`messenger-thread.js`

```
const pad = require.main.require('../js/funcs/pad.js');

module.exports = class {
  constructor() {
    process.on('message', message => {
      this.receive(message.command, message.data);
    });
    this.commands = {};
  }
  on(command, func){
    this.commands[command] = func;
    let processPadded = pad(process.pid, 6);
    console.log("thread [", processPadded, "] listening for command:", command);
  }
  receive(command, data) {
    command = command.trim(); // just to prove that's not the issue
    let processPadded = pad(process.pid, 6);
    console.log("thread [", processPadded, "] recieving", command, data)
    if (this.commands[command]) this.commands[command](data);
    else {
      //this is the code that should not be executing
      console.log("command", command, "was received by [", processPadded, "] but had no listener", this.commands, this.commands[command], command, typeof command);
    }
  }
  emit(command, data){
    let processPadded = pad(process.pid, 6);
    console.log("thread [", processPadded, "] sending", command, data)
    process.send({ command, data });
  }
}
```

The output makes no sense at all!

```
thread [ 311752 ] listening for command: process-results
... snip ...
command process-results was received by [ 311752 ] but had no listener {
  'process-symbol-complete-ack': [Function],
  'process-symbol': [Function],
  sleep: [Function],
  'process-results': [Function]
} undefined process-results string
```

How can `this.commands[command]` resolve to `undefined` while in the very same console log, `{ ... snip ... 'process-results': [Function] }` shows that exact property is a function?

---

The following code probably isn't relevant to the issue, but included for perspective: There's also a master version of the class for the cluster.isMaster thread:

`messenger-master.js`

```
const Worker = require.main.require('../js/classes/worker.js');

module.exports = class {
  constructor(workers) {
    this.workers = workers;
    this.wrappedWorkers = [];
    this.workers.forEach(worker => {
      this.wrappedWorkers.push(new Worker(worker));
    });
  }
  init(func){
    func(this.wrappedWorkers);
  }
  broadcast(command, data) {
    this.wrappedWorkers.forEach(worker => {
      worker.emit(command, data);
    })
  }
}
```

and a worker wrapper class that goes with it:

`worker.js`

```
module.exports = class {
  constructor(worker) {
    this.worker = worker;
    worker.on('message', message => {
      this.receive(message.command, message.data);
    });
    this.commands = {};
  }
  on(command, func){
    this.commands[command] = func;
  }
  receive(command, data) {
    if (this.commands[command]) this.commands[command](data);
  }
  emit(command, data){
    console.log("master sending", command, data)
    this.worker.send({ command, data });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Where I invoked the message, I had gone through the code adding `.yellow`, `.red` etc to strings in console logs for the color Node.js module. `messenger.on("process-results".yellow` was an accidental placement of one of those modifiers, and in the logs it all looks perfect, but there were hidden char codes that wouldnt be logged.

`command.split("").map(x => x.charCodeAt(0)))` revealed this. @VLAZ checked the contents in the chatroom, somethin like this:

```
||> [ 27, 91, 51, 51, 109, 112, 114, 111, 99, 101, 115, 115, 45, 114, 101, 115, 117, 108, 116, 115, 27, 91, 51, 57, 109 ].map(x => String.fromCharCode(x))

["\u001b","[","3","3","m","p","r","o","c","e","s","s","-","r","e","s","u","l","t","s","\u001b","[","3","9","m"] Logged: ``
```

Comment: Thanks @VLAZ for the help